# You've just acquired a newly created CentOS server, what should you do to secure it?

Tags: web-application, linux, webserver

I've just acquired a new CentOS server, which will be hosting a Ruby on rails application, it is public facing. What should I do to secure this server?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to harden it by using the DISA/STIG (Security Technical Implementation Guides) compliance standards which are published by the department of defence.

They are quite comprehensive and exhaustive when it comes to server hardening. You can find them here: http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/.

Aside from server hardening you also need to make sure your app is written in accordance to the OWASP web application best practices.

Aside from a normal firewall you should also deploy a Web Application Firewall (WAF) such as mod_security and a host based intrusion detection system (OSSEC).

Preferably you do not expose management interfaces such as SSH on the public IP and all logging should be done towards a separate loging server (of course if your server infrastructure only covers this single server that might not be an issue).

Answer (score 3):

The answer: **it depends**.

While you absolutely need to make yourself familiar with elements in @LucasKauffman answer, you also need to understand that implementing the best practices will take time. And it also means maintaining them in the future.

I don't install the latest & greatest alarm system on my 95 toyota corolla. So it all comes down to identifying the risks and the costs of not mitigating them.

What will your server host? Will you keep credit card numbers (which I hope not!) ? Are you more at risks for random server scanners or a hacker dedicated to breaking your webapp ? All this should be part of your risk analysis.

There are certainly a baseline you can achieve that is common sense (and doesnt cost a lot):

1. Keep your softwares up to date
2. Make sure unecessary ports are closed
3. Create a user with low privileges but which can ssh and sudo into root
4. Disable root login on ssh
5. Use a good known framework for your webapp, don't start from scratch
6. Have your code reviewed by a third party

This is not, by far, an exhaustive list. But this is a starting point.